# Poor performance when parsing JSON - JsonTextWriter as an alternative?

Tags: c#, json

I'm using the code below to parse a JSON response back from the server. It's a little slow. I'm wanting to know if I should be using the JsonTextWriter as an alternative?

How would I implement this using the JsonTextWriter?

```
string responseString = string.Empty;
Uri uri = new Uri ("http://localhost/complex-json.json");
HttpWebRequest request = new HttpWebRequest (uri);
request.Method = "GET";

HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse () as HttpWebResponse;
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())) {
responseString = sr.ReadToEnd ();
}
response.Close ();

JObject obj = JObject.Parse (responseString);
JArray a = (JArray)obj["questions"];
IList<question> questions = a.ToObject<IList<question>>();
for (int i = 0; i < a.Count; i++) {
 Console.WriteLine(questions[0].answer_count);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

System.Web.Extensions.dll has a `JavaScriptSerializer`. I use the following 2 extension methods to serialize and deserialize:

```
public static T JsonDeserialize<T>(this string json)
        {
            return new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<T>(json);
        }

public static string ToJson<T>(this T item)
        {
            return new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(item);
        }
```

Hope this helps.